# Exchange 2007 - forwarding all users' email

Tags: exchange-2007, forwarding

Admin newbie question, so apologies if it's totally obvious.

Is there a way to forward all recipients' email to another domain? I can set up delivery options for each user individually, but is there a setting that would let me say "whenever there's an email for user x on this domain, also forward it to user x on another domain"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting out with researching the "targetAddress" attribute on the user object in AD (ADSIedit.msc).

Be very careful making changes here.  What you are wanting to do typically involves manually creating a contact object with external SMTP address.. then forwarding email to contact (and to users mailbox), so this scenario is not native to Exchange 2007 and will be a little messy.

Comment: I'll have a look at ADSledit, thank you. I think I wasn't very clear in the question. What I'm after is a way of forwarding a copy of whatever comes in for domain A to another domain B.

Comment: Hub transport rule to trigger the forwarding.. then set up a connector to the second domain.  Users in one of the domains would need smtp addresses configured and the second domain would possibly need to be configured as authoritatuve for the original domain.  You could script this or use something like ADModify.  It could be done, but would require a little planning.